# Parsing coordinates from JSON in a loop

Tags: python, json, loops

I am parsing the latitude and longitude coordinates from a JSON object.

At the moment I am doing this

```
    tenMileRadius = 'http://chargepoints.dft.gov.uk/api/retrieve/registry/lat/' + str(latitude) + '/long/' + str(longitude) + '/dist/10/format/json'

    # GET The 10 closest devices to the given postcode
    response = requests.get(tenMileRadius).json()
    
    alat = response['ChargeDevice'][0]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    blat = response['ChargeDevice'][1]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    clat = response['ChargeDevice'][2]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    dlat = response['ChargeDevice'][3]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    elat = response['ChargeDevice'][4]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    flat = response['ChargeDevice'][5]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    glat = response['ChargeDevice'][6]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    hlat = response['ChargeDevice'][7]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    ilat = response['ChargeDevice'][8]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']
    jlat = response['ChargeDevice'][9]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Latitude']

    alon = response['ChargeDevice'][0]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    blon = response['ChargeDevice'][1]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    clon = response['ChargeDevice'][2]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    dlon = response['ChargeDevice'][3]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    elon = response['ChargeDevice'][4]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    flon = response['ChargeDevice'][5]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    glon = response['ChargeDevice'][6]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    hlon = response['ChargeDevice'][7]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    ilon = response['ChargeDevice'][8]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
    jlon = response['ChargeDevice'][9]['ChargeDeviceLocation']['Longitude']
```

However I realise this is inelegant and low level, and that the number of coords returnt will vary - which this method misses. How can I access the coords by iterating through the JSON, so that I have my coords in this format -

```
coords = [[latitude, longitude],
    [latitude, longitude],
    [latitude, longitude],
    [latitude, longitude],
    [latitude, longitude]]
```

The JSON looks like this

```
   {'Scheme':
    {'SchemeCode': 'NA', 'SchemeData':
    {'OrganisationName': 'NA', 'Website': 'NA', 'TelephoneNo': 'NA'}},
    'ChargeDevice': [{'ChargeDeviceId': 'bc783b8d7776bd472c216a4672883f8b',
    'ChargeDeviceLocation': {'Latitude': '55.326762', 'Longitude': '-1.582318', ...
  {'ChargeDeviceId': 'f39dfe556bde4e399ff9df50170b13b6', 'ChargeDeviceRef': 'GP11934'...
    'ChargeDeviceLocation': {'Latitude': '52.554362', 'Longitude': '-1.382325' ...
{'ChargeDeviceId': '179ddc389a9324cebba038fb4ac783d5', 'ChargeDeviceRef': 'GP11960', ....
    'ChargeDeviceLocation': {'Latitude': '52.765253', 'Longitude': '-0.881864'....
```

Comment: can you post an example json file, can't seem to access that link.

Comment: I've added an edited down portion showing the structure of the JSON to my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to extract all of the lat/lon coordinates.

```
coordinates = [
[device['chargeDeviceLocation']['latitude'],
 device['chargeDeviceLocation']['longitude']] \
for device in response['chargeDevice']]
```